# code that does what the home button is supposed to do in a line of text

Tags: arabic, right-to-left

I have an arabic line with english letters in it.
Ex: أنا في abcd البيت

I opened notepad. I started writing.
What I wanted to write is I'm at abcd home but what you see now (left to right) is at I'm abcd home

To fix this, I click anywhere on that line. I press the HOME button. You'll see the cursor moving to the beginning of the arabic word that to the left of the english word. I right click, choose INSERT UNICODE CONTROL CHARACTER then I choose RLE.

When i do that, the reads I'm at abcd home. It's fixed.

If you right click again and choose SHOW UNICODE CONTROL CHARACTER. you'll see that the very first "character" is the unicode character I inserted.

I wish to automate this process.

How do I do that? :D

I can tell you that RLE is represented as \u202B

Thanx

Comment: Thank you for this question. See the reply below. I hope that it's helpful. It's relevant for all right-to-left languages, such as Persian, Urdu, Yiddish and Hebrew so I added the "right-to-left" tag.

Answer (score 1):

There's no very easy way to automate the process, but there are a couple of things that you can try:

1. Press Ctrl-Shift on the right-hand side of your keyboard. This will work in Notepad and in many other programs on Windows: Word, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome. It may work in Firefox, too, but if it doesn't, use Ctrl-Shift-X to set right-to-left direction in Firefox. Note that this will correct the display of the text and the cursor movement for you while you are writing it, but not necessarily for the people to whom you send this text.
2. Use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to add the RLE character to your keyboard. This program will let you create a new keyboard layout that you will be able to use in all the programs. Load the keyboard layout that you are currently using, find a key that is not assigned to any character and assign the RLE to it. Note that if you use RLE, you must also use the PDF character (U+202C) in the end of the right-to-left text, so assign this to some key, too (this is similar to writing <span dir="rtl">أنا في abcd البيت<span> in HTML—you must use the closing tag). This will fix your text, although it's tricky. Also, note that some websites remove characters like RLE when you try to post on them - Facebook and Twitter do this, for example.

Finally, note that this problem is unique to plain text. If you use a real word processor, like MS-Word or LibreOffice, or write your text as HTML with proper dir attributes, then it's a lot easier, but you'll have to store and send your text in these formats.